# font-awesome error: Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: yeoman, font-awesome, yeoman-generator-angular

I have searches a lot, but I haven't find the solution.

I use generator-angular to generate the project and have font-awesome involved, but I got the warning in chrome

```
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://gview.com/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0"
```

I notice there are some rules in the generated .htaccess file to handle the font MIME type, I do not know why it can not work for me.

Besides, I use ui.router for the view route, and on the purpose of getting rid of the #, I add some rules in the .htaccess as follows:

RewriteEngine on

```
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

I can not figure out where is the wrong.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Grunt to serve your application, you might need to make a small change to allow other file extensions through.

```
connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
            hostname: 'localhost',
            livereload: 35729
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        modRewrite(['!\\.html|\\.js|\\.svg|\\.css|\\.png|\\.woff|\\.ttf|\\.gif$ /index.html [L]']),
```

Check the modRewrite in your Gruntfile to ensure you have all of the file extensions that you need.